# What is the disadvantage If I alter the char size of existing column field size in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to increase the column size of my existing table. I can change it. But I wants to know will it give me the problem later?.

Is there any disadvantage because of it?

Comment: As long as you make sure the exiting data is not corrupted or casted wrongly, there are no disadvantages in increasing the column size.

Comment: @Kobydouek is there a change to corrupted on that field?.. Or will it get corrupted the entire table?

Comment: What is the column type?

Comment: @Kobydouek char(35), I want to increase to char(60), not only this field. other field also i want to modify

Comment: Then there shouldn't be any issues. It's safe to increase it.

Comment: One point : `Running ALTER COLUMN without mentioning attribute NOT NULL will result in the column being changed to nullable, if it is already not.`

Comment: Why do you want to use `char(60)`? Are all the values a fixed length of 60 characters? Seems unlikely as they were previously 35. You should be using `varchar(60)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are keeping the column the same "type", so you mean:

```
alter table alter column col varchar(max);  -- for some varchar
alter table alter column col bigint;        -- where the column is a smaller int
```

(This is more general than the OP's question; I notice in the title the question specifically refers to character data.)

Then there are unlikely to be "future" problems.  Any existing data should fit in the "larger" data type.

When you make the change, SQL Server may need to restructure the database pages, so it might take some time.  However, that is a short-term consideration, not a long-term consideration.  Well, sort of short-term.  The restructuring could cause fragmentation -- but this is less likely with `varchar()` changes.

If any of the columns are used for foreign key references, you may find that you cannot make the change -- unless you drop the foreign key constraint and rebuild it.

Obviously, the data will probably take up more space on disk and in memory (although this is a minor consideration for `varchar()` and `nvarchar()`, because those are variable length).

The additional space can somewhat increase the run-time of queries.  There are borderline worst-case scenarios where the increased space means that the data pages for the table don't fit into memory, and you can get into a thrashing situation for some queries.  That is highly unlikely, though -- and would happen anyway with a few more rows or pages that are less filled.

This can also affect indexes that use those columns.